# Using $resource in AngularJS and getting an undefined response

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
vm.getTheSector = function () {
  SectorDataFactory.get({action:'getSector', sectorName:vm.selected}, function (response) {
      vm.industry.sector = response.theSector;
  });

  vm.saveTheIndustry()
};

vm.saveTheIndustry = function () {
    SectorDataFactory.save({action: 'saveIndustry'}, vm.industry, function (response) {
        vm.responseMessage = response.theMessage;
    });
};
```

I am getting a sector object from a RESTful web service however `vm.industry.sector` is undefined. I'm trying to then POST the industry object however the sector is null.

Comment: You are doing it too soon, put `vm.saveTheIndustry()` inside success callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.getTheSector = function () {
    SectorDataFactory.get({action: 'getSector', sectorName: vm.selected}, function (response) {
        vm.industry.sector = response.theSector;

        vm.saveTheIndustry()
    });


};
```

Thanks to mbeso. The `vm.saveTheIndustry()` now executes as part of the success callback.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you.